# ErrorException Undefined index: process (Actualizando Laravel 6 a 7)

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, composer

Estoy intentando actualizar Laravel desde la versión 6 a la 7. Utilizo PHP 7.3 ya que es la última versión que me ofrece el servidor en producción.

En local funciono perfecto la actualización, trabajo con vagrant y composer 2.x, modifiqué composer.json, handler.php en App/Exceptions y session.php en config.

El problema llegó cuando quise actualizar en producción, primero corrí composer install con composer 1.x y nunca llegó a terminar, cortaba el proceso por exceso de tiempo, actualize a composer 2.x, volví a correr composer install y hace el proceso pero se corta con este error:

[ErrorException] Undefined index: process

Aquí una captura del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como el error sucedía luego de nunomaduro/collision bajé su versión a 3.x, volví a ejecutar composer install y me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que es una librería de desarrollo luego probé con composer install --no-dev y sucedió el mismo error pero pasó a estar luego de laravel/ui, adjunto captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí quedé por ahora, sigo haciendo pruebas, agradezco aportes y si encuentro solución lo comento por acá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he podido solucionar el problema y actualicé hasta Laravel 8, última versión hoy día.

Symfony trabaja con "Process" y no se podía instalar ya que composer 2 no corría correctamente, el problema estaba en php.ini, tenía proc_open y varios otros proc_* en disable_functions, los removí y la actualización corrió correctamente, incluso llevando symfony a la versión 5.

Dicho sea de paso, es buena práctica en producción correr composer install agregando --no-dev para no instalar librerías innecesarias.

Otra modificación que tuve que realizar obligado en esta actualización fue llevar memory_limit de php.ini arriba de 1700m, lo establecí en 2048m.